# Making a temporary list

Tags: groovy

Why doesn't this work (`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method unique() on null object`):

```
println([1,2,3] + [3,4]).unique()
```

and this does:

```
println(([1,2,3] + [3,4]).unique())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is calling the `println()` method (which has a return type of `void`) then trying to invoke `unique()` on it. This causes a `NullPointerException`.

The second is creating a new `java.util.ArrayList`, then calling `unique()` on that list, then printing it to the console.